# React Form Returns Undefined Values

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Form ({handleSubmit, handleChange, value}) {
  return (
    <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="name" onChange = {handleChange}/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to create a basic ToDoList App. I'm getting stuck on the part in which you render the users input into my ToDoList Component. When I alert the value of e.target.value I get undefined. What is the problem?  EDIT:  Added my form component.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import Form from "./Form.js";
import {useState} from "react";
import ToDoList from "./ToDoList.js"

export default function App() {
  const[items, setItems] = useState([]);
  let value = "";
  function handleChange(e) {
    value = e.target.value;
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    setItems([...items,
      e.target.value
    ]);
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + e.target.value); 
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div> 
      <Header/>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <Form handleChange = {handleChange} handleSubmit = {handleSubmit} value = {value}/>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <ToDoList items = {items}/>
      </div>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Add `Form` component

Comment: thanks for the welcome. I added my form component, let me know if you can spot the problem.

Comment: the form doesn't hold your value, the input does. (e.target is the form for submit events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you pass whole form as event to `handleSubmit` and `items`. If you want to keep this style of code, you must use input value changes. Also you must define `e.preventDefault()` before doing everything. So:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import Form from "./Form.js";
import {useState} from "react";
import ToDoList from "./ToDoList.js"

export default function App() {
  const[inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  const[items, setItems] = useState([]);
  let value = "";
  function handleChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setItems([...items,
      inputValue
    ]);
    setInputValue("");
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + e.target.value); 
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div> 
      <Header/>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <Form handleChange={handleChange} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} value = {value}/>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <ToDoList items = {items}/>
      </div>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: e.preventDefault being first is a preventative measure to avoid it not being called in the event of an error. it isn't necessarily a requirement, just a good idea